# Generating ill-formed "XML" without root element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using Python library Elementtree to parse XML. I am editing that XML and now I want to solve a problem: I need to generate XML that doesn't have root element.

From output:

```
<MyRoot>
    <Type>
      something...
    </Type>
    <Type>
      ...
    </Type>
        <Type>
          ...
        </Type>
</MyRoot>
```

So for example it must generate this XML:

```
<Type>
  something...
</Type>
<Type>
  ...
</Type>
<Type>
  ...
</Type>
```

Can you help me? I Hope you understand what I need.

I need this for another software which unfortunately does only handle XML without root element, which I dont't understand.

Comment: XML document w/o root/docElement isn't a well formed XML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to find a simple invocation to do this as it's "bad" XML.

You've got two approaches at I can think of:

1. Render to string with `<MyRoot>` and strip it off with string operations
2. Render all the children of `<MyRoot>` to string and concatenate them yourself.

Of the two non-ideal options, I personally prefer the second.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over your elements,  call the `ElementTree.tostring` function on each element, and concatenate the resulting strings.